# mysql query tuning

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that I have made into a MYSQL view.  This particular view is central to our application so we are looking at tuning it.  There is a primary key on Map_Id,User_No,X,Y.  I am pretty comfortable tuning SQL server queries but not totally sure about how MySql works in this aspect.  Would it help to put an index on it that covers points and update_stamp as well?  Reads on this table are 90% so while it has lots of inserts, it does not compare to the amount of reads.

Description:  Get the person with the most points for each x,y coord in a given map.  Tie break by who has the latest update stamp and then by user id.

```
    SELECT GP.Map_Id AS Map_Id,GP.User_No AS User_No,GP.X AS X,GP.Y AS Y, GP.Points AS Points,GP.Update_Stamp AS Update_Stamp
    FROM (Grid_Points GP LEFT JOIN Grid_Points GP2
         ON (
       (
        (GP2.Map_Id = GP.Map_Id) AND (GP2.X = GP.X) AND (GP2.Y = GP.Y) AND 
        ((GP2.Points > GP.Points) OR ((GP2.Points = GP.Points) AND (GP2.Update_Stamp > GP.Update_Stamp)) OR 
        ((GP2.Points = GP.Points) AND (GP2.Update_Stamp = GP.Update_Stamp) AND (GP2.User_No < GP.User_No)))
       )
  )
 )

WHERE ISNULL(GP2.User_No);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow man, you really like to use parentheses.  :-)

You're right, a compound index may help.  You might even be able to make it a covering index.  Probably either an index on `Grid_Points(Map_Id,X,Y)` or else an index on `Grid_Points(Points,Update_Stamp,User_No)` would be what I try.

Always test query optimization with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) to see if the optimizer is using your index.  Read that documentation section until you understand the cryptic notes in the EXPLAIN report.

The EXPLAIN report will probably show you which index it decides to use.  You should be aware that **MySQL uses only one index per table** in a given query.

Here's how I would write that query, relying on order of precedence between `AND` and `OR` instead of so many nested parentheses:

```
SELECT GP.Map_Id, GP.User_No, GP.X, GP.Y, GP.Points, GP.Update_Stamp
FROM Grid_Points GP LEFT JOIN Grid_Points GP2
  ON GP2.Map_Id = GP.Map_Id AND GP2.X = GP.X AND GP2.Y = GP.Y
    AND (
      GP2.Points > GP.Points
      OR
        GP2.Points = GP.Points
        AND GP2.Update_Stamp > GP.Update_Stamp
      OR
        GP2.Points = GP.Points
        AND GP2.Update_Stamp = GP.Update_Stamp
        AND GP2.User_No < GP.User_No
    )
WHERE GP2.User_No IS NULL;
```

You are using my favorite method for finding greatest-n-per-group in MySQL.  MySQL doesn't optimize `GROUP BY` very well (it often incurs a temporary table which gets serialized to disk), so the left outer join solution that you're using is usually a lot better, at least for MySQL.  In other brands of RDBMS, this solution may not have such an advantage.

Comment: Actually I hate all the parentheses, but I had to export the view to see the structure and it had put them in.  I did do an explain and saw it was doing a full scan.  I will try a covering index.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks for the info. BTW I tested my solution on some sample data, and its about the same speed, I didn't know about the other way of doing this. The real solution as you mention is in the index,  Map_Id,X,Y helps a lot more than Points,Update_Stamp,User_No
Care you explain how this query works/ where I can read up on this style?

Comment: Follow the `greatest-n-per-group` tag here at StackOverflow.  There are dozens of similar problems with solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't match it to itself, I'd do it as a "group by" and then possibly match back to get who the person is.

SELECT Map_Id, X, Y, max(Points)
FROM Grid_Points
GROUP BY Map_Id, X, Y;

This would give you a table of Map_Id, X, and Y, then the maximum points.
You could then join those results back to Grid_Points to find which user is = to those points.

Comment: Also you'd want to index (not a unique index just an index)
Map_Id, X, Y, Points

Comment: We did start with the max and group by and changed to our current method.  I will try both to see the performance difference.